# Python select dropdown value with requests

Tags: python-requests

Hello I have this simple html select options:

```
<select name="dnn$ctr6707$TimeTableView$ClassesList" id="dnn_ctr6707_TimeTableView_ClassesList" class="HeaderClasses">

<option selected="selected" value="14">ז1ש</option>

<option value="15">ז2ש</option>

<option value="16">ז3ש</option>

<option value="17">ז4ש</option>

<option value="49">ז5ש</option>

<option value="60">ז6ש</option>

<option value="24">ז7ש</option>

<option value="1">ז8ד</option>

<option value="2">ז9ד</option>

<option value="3">ז10ד</option>

<option value="4">ז11ד</option>

<option value="5">ח1ד</option>

<option value="6">ח2ד</option>

<option value="7">ח3ד</option>

<option value="8">ח4ד</option>

<option value="999">ח5ד</option>

<option value="18">ח6ש</option>

<option value="19">ח7ש</option>

<option value="20">ח8ש</option>

 </select></td>
```

The form data for the table is ""dnn$ctr6707$TimeTableView$ClassesList"" However when i **Get request** it, The value of the class table doesn't change it stays on 14.
This is the website if you want to try: http://tikah.iscool.co.il/default.aspx
If you can provide me with get request that changes the value or explain (better with code) i will appreciate it! 
Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
def main():
    dat = {
        '__EVENTTARGET': 'dnn_ctr6707_TimeTableView_TdChangesTable',
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'CA0B0334',
        'dnn$ctr6707$TimeTableView$ClassesList': 42,
        'dnn$ctr6707$TimeTableView$ControlId': 2
    }
    responde = requests.get('http://tikah.iscool.co.il/default.aspx', data=dat)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Picking option that has the value of 42

Comment: I assume you are making a POST somewhere? Can you show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets me a status code of 200, so i assume you can get whatever info you need from there.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs



url=r'http://tikah.iscool.co.il/default.aspx'

s=requests.Session()
r=s.get(url)


soup=bs(r.text,'html.parser')

dataload={
    '__EVENTTARGET': 'dnn$ctr6707$TimeTableView$ClassesList',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    '__LASTFOCUS': '',
    '__VIEWSTATE': soup.find('input',{'id':'__VIEWSTATE'}).attrs['value'],
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': soup.find('input',{'id':'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'}).attrs['value'],
    'dnn$ctr6707$TimeTableView$ClassesList': '42',
    'dnn$ctr6707$TimeTableView$ControlId': '',
    'ScrollTop':'' ,
    '__dnnVariable': ''
}



headers={
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'content-length': '3278',
    'Host': 'tikah.iscool.co.il',
    'Origin': 'http://tikah.iscool.co.il',
    'Referer': 'http://tikah.iscool.co.il/default.aspx',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36'

}

r=s.post(r.url,headers=headers,data=dataload)
print(r.status_code)
```

**Explanation:**

When i inspected the post request, i saw that there were some parameters getting passed that were unique to every browsing session (__VIEWSTATE and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR in this case). So these values have to come from somewhere. I inspected the elements in the page and found the hidden inputs like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUIMjU3MTQzOTcPZBYGZg8WAh4EVGV4dAU+PCF........
```

So then it was just a matter of using BeautifulSoup to parse out the 'value' attribute and putting that in my `dataload` dict. If you haven't used BS before, i'd recommend reading the docs [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Thank you it works, can you explain what you did on the dataload ‘__viewstate’?

Comment: @yarinCohen i added some explanation in my answer